# Improving performance p5.js Metaballs

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Coding Metaballs for fun, wanting to experiment with more balls, higher resolutions, different color pallets, etc., but the performance currently is terrible. Where can I improve? Maybe shaders or something? I don't know if that's possible with what I'm doing, I think WebGL might work, but I've never messed with that.

```js
const balls = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 200);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) balls.push(new Ball(random(width), random(height)))
}

function draw() {
  loadPixels();
  for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      let sum = 0;
      for (const ball of balls) {
        let dx = ball.pos.x - x;
        let dy = ball.pos.y - y;
        let d = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
        sum += ball.r / d;
      }
      set(x, y, color((11 > sum) * 255));
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
  
  for (const ball of balls) ball.update(balls);
}
const BASE_SPEED = 1.5;

class Ball {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.pos = {
      x: x,
      y: y
    }
    
    this.angle = random(0, 2 * Math.PI);
    
    this.vel = {
      x: BASE_SPEED * cos(this.angle),
      y: BASE_SPEED * sin(this.angle)
    }
    
     this.r = 150;
  }
  
  update() {
    this.pos.x += this.vel.x;
    this.pos.y += this.vel.y;
    
    if (this.pos.x < 0 || this.pos.x > width) this.vel.x *= -1;
    if (this.pos.y < 0 || this.pos.y > height) this.vel.y *= -1;
    
    for (const ball of balls) {
      if (ball == this) return;
      
      const dx = ball.pos.x - this.pos.x;
      const dy = ball.pos.y - this.pos.y;
      
      const d = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
      
      this.vel.x += dx / (d * 10);
      this.vel.y += dy / (d * 10);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: I read it as Meatballs, which I know a lot more about.

Comment: @DaveNewton 

Comment: Yes using WebGL with a fragment shader will massively improve performance: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/wd3SzS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple translation of the rendering portion of your JavaScript code into GLSL. All of the ball state and updating code is still in JavaScript.

Shaders work by executing a function once per pixel to determine what color that pixel should be. Which is very similar to your JavaScript code for rendering. However when you implement this as a shader it is way faster because many of those operations happen in parallel instead of sequentially.

I increased the number of balls to 13 to demonstrate the performance.

```js
let metaballShader;
let balls = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  
  metaballShader =
    createShader(
      // vertex program:
      `attribute vec3 aPosition;

      // Uniforms allow you to pass information from JavaScript to your shader
      uniform float width;
      uniform float height;

      // Varying values pass data from the vertex shader to the fragment shader
      // their values will be smoothly interpolated from one vertex to the next
      varying highp vec2 vPos;

      void main() {
        // convert position attribute into screen position (-1, -1) to (1, 1)
        gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
        // convert position in screen space to position in pixel space
        vPos = vec2(
          (gl_Position.x + 1.) / 2. * width,
          (gl_Position.y + 1.) / 2. * height);
      }`,
      // fragment shader:
      `precision highp float;

      #define BALLS 13

      uniform float xs[BALLS];
      uniform float ys[BALLS];
      uniform float rs[BALLS];

      varying highp vec2 vPos;

      // called once per pixel (equivalent to the body of your for loops over x and y)
      void main() {
        float sum = 0.;
  
        // calculate the sum value for the current pixel (vPos.x, vPos.y)
        for (int i = 0; i < BALLS; i++) {
          float dx = xs[i] - vPos.x;
          float dy = ys[i] - vPos.y;
          float d = length(vec2(dx, dy));
          sum += rs[i] / d;
        }

        // Set the pixel color based on the sum of distances to the balls
        if (sum > 11.) {
          gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0.), 1.);
        } else {
          gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(1.), 1.);
        }
      }`
    );
  
  shader(metaballShader);
  for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    balls.push(new Ball(random(width), random(height)));
  }
  
  metaballShader.setUniform('width', width);
  metaballShader.setUniform('height', height);
  metaballShader.setUniform('rs', balls.map(b => b.r));
}

function draw() {
  metaballShader.setUniform('xs', balls.map(b => b.pos.x));
  metaballShader.setUniform('ys', balls.map(b => b.pos.y));
  quad(-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1);
  for (const ball of balls) {
    ball.update(balls);
  }
}

const BASE_SPEED = 0.8;

class Ball {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.pos = {
      x: x,
      y: y
    }
    
    this.angle = random(0, 2 * Math.PI);
    
    this.vel = {
      x: BASE_SPEED * cos(this.angle),
      y: BASE_SPEED * sin(this.angle)
    }
    
     this.r = 100;
  }
  
  update() {
    this.pos.x += this.vel.x;
    this.pos.y += this.vel.y;
    
    if (this.pos.x < 0 || this.pos.x > width) this.vel.x *= -1;
    if (this.pos.y < 0 || this.pos.y > height) this.vel.y *= -1;
    
    for (const ball of balls) {
      if (ball == this) return;
      
      const dx = ball.pos.x - this.pos.x;
      const dy = ball.pos.y - this.pos.y;
      
      const d = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
      
      this.vel.x += dx / (d * 20);
      this.vel.y += dy / (d * 20);
      
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Here's your original code with 13 balls for perf comparison:

```js
const balls = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) balls.push(new Ball(random(width), random(height)))
}

function draw() {
  loadPixels();
  for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      let sum = 0;
      for (const ball of balls) {
        let dx = ball.pos.x - x;
        let dy = ball.pos.y - y;
        let d = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
        sum += ball.r / d;
      }
      set(x, y, color((11 > sum) * 255));
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
  
  for (const ball of balls) ball.update(balls);
}
const BASE_SPEED = 1.5;

class Ball {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.pos = {
      x: x,
      y: y
    }
    
    this.angle = random(0, 2 * Math.PI);
    
    this.vel = {
      x: BASE_SPEED * cos(this.angle),
      y: BASE_SPEED * sin(this.angle)
    }
    
     this.r = 100;
  }
  
  update() {
    this.pos.x += this.vel.x;
    this.pos.y += this.vel.y;
    
    if (this.pos.x < 0 || this.pos.x > width) this.vel.x *= -1;
    if (this.pos.y < 0 || this.pos.y > height) this.vel.y *= -1;
    
    for (const ball of balls) {
      if (ball == this) return;
      
      const dx = ball.pos.x - this.pos.x;
      const dy = ball.pos.y - this.pos.y;
      
      const d = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
      
      this.vel.x += dx / (d * 10);
      this.vel.y += dy / (d * 10);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: the performance difference is insane. where are some places I could learn GLSL?

Comment: Here is a really good and extensive tutorial regarding using shaders with p5.js: https://itp-xstory.github.io/p5js-shaders/#/  

Here's a little tutorial I wrote about some of the nuances of shaders in p5.js and using them for 2d displays (like your Metaballs) vs 3d applications: https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1202168

Comment: Here's another useful resource: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-shaders-and-glsl.html

Comment: Cool, appreciate it!